# How to extract text from .docx with tables in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx

The .docx file I have has tables, headers, etc. and I was wondering how I could extract text from that document. The only example code I could find uses paragraphs, and it doesn't work with my file.

Here is the code:

```
    doc = docx.Document(self.filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        txt = para.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        fullText.append(txt)
    self.text = '\n'.join(fullText)
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
 File "annotatorConnections.py", line 75, in openFile
    self.text = '\n'.join(fullText)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting a byte type instead of a string type in your fullText, you can use this to get this working :

```
doc = docx.Document(self.filename)
fullText = []
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    txt = para.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    fullText.append(txt)
self.text = b'\n'.join(fullText)             ---------> Add prefix b to make it a byte object.
```